# Magento rest api: how to get orders by ids?

Tags: magento, rest, magento-1.8

How to get multiple orders filtered by Id from magento with help of rest api?

I tryed to use `http://192.168.0.104:4422/magento/api/rest/orders?filter[1][attribute]=entity_id&filter[1][in]=1&filter[1][in]=3`

but it returns me:

```
<magento_api>
<messages>
<error>
<data_item>
<code>401</code>
<message>oauth_problem=signature_invalid</message>
</data_item>
</error>
</messages>
</magento_api>
```

But if i use request with only one filter `in` parameter `http://192.168.0.104:4422/magento/api/rest/orders?filter[1][attribute]=entity_id&filter[1][in]=1` - it works great.

Comment: did u create the rest user role for it?

Comment: Yes, magento and all other stuf is well configured, the problem appears only in request with multiple 'in'parameter.

Comment: @burzhuy, did you managed to resolve this? i'm curious to find out too.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in filters( I tried on 1.7.0.1). Looks like some magento versions have problems with filters. So you should use 1 filter, after that filter results in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [in this blog post](http://magentoforce.com/2014/08/magento-rest-api-multiple-in-get-filters/). In short, if you follow this structure (this was for my use case with a list of products):

```
http://magentohost.com/api/rest/products?filter[1][attribute]=entity_id&filter[1][in][1]=1&filter[1][in][2]=3
```

You'll be set! (this gets two products similar to above with ids 1 and 3). Notice the `[1]` and `[2]` after both of the `[in]`. I wish Magento had better documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregating values.

```
complexFilter { key = "increment_id", value = new associativeEntity {key = "in", value = "1,2,3"} };
```